# Infrequent existence of node in xml elements

Tags: xml, asp-classic, xml-parsing

```
 <ObjectArrayToXml xmlns="http://www.something.com/">
      <itemslist>
        <Size>18</Size>
        <ItemInfo>
          <Pass>5225</Pass>
          <AgentName>aaaaaa</AgentName>
          <Document>6763</Document>
        </ItemInfo>
        <ItemInfo>
          <Pass>1223</Pass>
          <Document>77755</Document>
**here the tag of AgentName will be missing
        </ItemInfo>
        <ItemInfo>
          <Pass>45344</Pass>
          <AgentName>bbbbbbb</AgentName>
          <Document>22234</Document>
        </ItemInfo>
      </itemslist>
    </ObjectArrayToXml>
```

we are getting the above structure with all 3 tags Pass,AgentName,Document for each item for more than 4 years
we been pharsing and printing it successfully like that:

```
Set NodeList = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("//ObjectArrayToXml/itemslist/ItemInfo")
     For Each Node In NodeList
response.write Node.selectSingleNode("Pass").text
response.write Node.selectSingleNode("AgentName").text
response.write Node.selectSingleNode("Document").text   
     Next
```

the structure of xml was changed and now we are not always getting the tag of AgentName  - it might not come at all for some of items.
I need to check now if tag exist for each item, then i wrote this code:

```
set xxx = xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//AgentName")
If Not xxx Is Nothing Then
response.write Node.selectSingleNode("AgentName").text
End If
```

it works great if ALL items has this tag or if ALL items doesn't have this tag. BUT once some items have this tag and others ain't then page crashes and i gives 500 error.
I realized that xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//AgentName") must looking the first item only and assume that all the rest items has same taga, and not checking each and every one of items for existance of AgentName tag.
I might not be right, can you advice how to check if this tag exist in each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `AgentName` of current `Node` in every iteration, try something like this inside the `For Each` loop :

```vb
set agentName = Node.selectSingleNode("AgentName")
If Not agentName Is Nothing Then
    response.write agentName.text
End If
```